# How to start a thread on ApplicationContext load in Spring MVC application?

Tags: spring, multithreading, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I am creating this Spring Web MVC application. I want to start a thread when the ApplicationContext starts loading. how should I do this??

Comment: You don't. You shouldn't be starting threads yourself, generally if you do you are doing things in the wrong way. What is the problem you are trying to solve with an additional thread?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this and its working

```
@Component
public class StartupApplicationListenerExample implements 
  ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private static final Logger LOG 
      = Logger.getLogger(StartupApplicationListenerExample.class);

    public static int counter;

    @Override public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        LOG.info("Increment counter");
        counter++;
    }
}
```